# Create Docker image on local machine using manifest.json and layers in the form of SHA

Tags: docker

I downloaded docker image in .zip format. which contains manifest.json and layers needed to create the docker image in the form of SHA. Is there any way to create docker image from it which I can use to run containers from it ?

I have following content inside my downloaded .zip file

[image]

Comment: Do you need to [`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) it?  Having an image in a local-file format at all is kind of unusual.

Comment: @DavidMaze If I use this command on .zip file, I am getting some error like ```archive/tar: invalid tar header```. Why it is in local file format ? I was facing some issue while doing docker build, so I downloaded zip from repository and thought like I can create image locally from it.